# Using AWS Cognito InitiateAuth action for app client with Azure AD SAML Identity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml, idp

We have a User Pool set up in AWS Cognito for which we have also set up Azure AD as a SAML Identity provider for one of the app clients

The authentication flow works as expected via the Hosted UI of this app client, with redirection to the IdP for authentication and generation of token following successful authentication against the IdP and redirection back to Cognito.

For app clients that are not using an Identity Provider we are able to use the `InitiateAuth` action (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) with an `AuthFlow` of `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` to allow users to authenticate and obtain tokens.

However, when we try and use the `InitiateAuth` action with the app client that is configured with the IdP, and use the the username automatically created by Cognito in the user pool (which by default is `<IdentityProviderName>_<UsernameOfUserOnIdP>` e.g. `AzureAD_matthew@domain.com`) and the same `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` as `AuthFlow` we get a `NotAuthorizedException`. So the following request:

```
{
    "AuthParameters": {
    "USERNAME": "AzureAD_matthew@domain.com",
    "PASSWORD": "XXXXXX"
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

is giving as this response:

```
{
    "__type": "NotAuthorizedException",
    "message": "Incorrect username or password."
}
```

Is it possible to use the `InitiateAuth` action for app clients that are linked to a SAML identity provider?

Thanks

Comment: That's because there is no password set for that user. If you set up the password it should work.

Comment: That's not the case - When using an Identity Provider the password is not stored or managed in any way by Cognito. That's the whole point of having the IdP.

Comment: So you are using USER_PASSWORD_AUTH. This assumes, well, a password. What password then?